# Symfony Bootrstrap do not load

Tags: css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys i have a problem with loading the default boot strap files. Here is my base code which load the css and js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

{% block title -%}<title>Admin</title>{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
  {% endblock %}
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
{% block menu -%} {% endblock %}
{% block body -%} {% endblock %}
{% block javascripts -%}
{% javascripts
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/fine-uploader.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/datatables.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js'

%}
<script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

After assets:instal and assetic:dump the bootstrap file has pointing to incorrect path see the image

[image]

It gets the file and rename it but it look fr the url in http://localhost:8000/css/Bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

I don't know why it gets this behavior. What can cause this problem?

Here are the files in @CoreBundle Resources

[image]

Comment: what is the name of the files that you have under /Resources/public/css

Comment: Here they are. You can see them on the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a problem with bootstrap files. So go to [bootsrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/) and download the full .zip file then copy and paste them to the right directory.